# Formatting academic references into bibtex

Tags: latex, reference-management

I am looking for a program or web service that can take as inputs a list of academic references in "plain text" format like MLA/APA/Chicago/etc, e.g.:

> - Addison, Paul S. " Wavelet transforms and the ECG: a review." Physiological measurement 26.5 (2005): R155.
> - Moody, G. B., and R. G. Mark. "Integration of real-time and off-line clinical data in the MIMIC database." Computers in Cardiology 1997.
>     IEEE, 1997.
> - Li, Cuiwei, Chongxun Zheng, and Changfeng Tai. "Detection of ECG characteristic points using wavelet transforms." Biomedical
>     Engineering, IEEE Transactions on 42.1 (1995): 21-28.
> - Unser, Michael, and Akram Aldroubi. "A review of wavelets in biomedical applications." Proceedings of the IEEE 84.4 (1996):
>     626-638.
> - JX Sun, AT Reisner, and RG Mark. A signal abnormality index for arterial blood pressure waveforms. In Computers in Cardiology, 2006,
>     pages 13–16. IEEE, 2006. Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning, Carl
>     Edward Rasmussen and Chris Williams, the MIT Press, 2006
> - JH Henriques and TR Rocha. Prediction of acute hypotensive episodes using neural network multi-models. In Computers in Cardiology, 2009,
>     pages 549–552. IEEE, 2009.

and as output would be the corresponding bibtex entries:

```
@article{addison2005wavelet,
  title={Wavelet transforms and the ECG: a review},
  author={Addison, Paul S},
  journal={Physiological measurement},
  volume={26},
  number={5},
  pages={R155},
  year={2005},
  publisher={IOP Publishing}
}

@inproceedings{moody1997integration,
  title={Integration of real-time and off-line clinical data in the MIMIC database},
  author={Moody, GB and Mark, RG},
  booktitle={Computers in Cardiology 1997},
  pages={585--588},
  year={1997},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@article{li1995detection,
  title={Detection of ECG characteristic points using wavelet transforms},
  author={Li, Cuiwei and Zheng, Chongxun and Tai, Changfeng},
  journal={Biomedical Engineering, IEEE Transactions on},
  volume={42},
  number={1},
  pages={21--28},
  year={1995},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@article{unser1996review,
  title={A review of wavelets in biomedical applications},
  author={Unser, Michael and Aldroubi, Akram},
  journal={Proceedings of the IEEE},
  volume={84},
  number={4},
  pages={626--638},
  year={1996},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{sun2006signal,
  title={A signal abnormality index for arterial blood pressure waveforms},
  author={Sun, JX and Reisner, AT and Mark, RG},
  booktitle={Computers in Cardiology, 2006},
  pages={13--16},
  year={2006},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@article{williams2006gaussian,
  title={Gaussian processes for machine learning},
  author={Williams, Christopher KI and Rasmussen, Carl Edward},
  journal={the MIT Press},
  volume={2},
  number={3},
  pages={4},
  year={2006}
}

@inproceedings{henriques2009prediction,
  title={Prediction of acute hypotensive episodes using neural network multi-models},
  author={Henriques, J and Rocha, TR},
  booktitle={Computers in Cardiology, 2009},
  pages={549--552},
  year={2009},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

Right now I use Google scholar to convert them manually one by one, which is tedious, and I would prefer to avoid using MTurk/oDesk/etc. Free and compatible with Windows 7 if possible.

Answer (score 2):

[**JabRef**](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) is a BibTeX bibliography manager:

- freeware / open-source
- Java based, so it is cross-platform
- reference management
- can send `\cite` key directly to TexStudio, LyX editors
- has a LibreOffice/OpenOffice [plugin](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/OOPlugin-jabref.php)

**It doesn't directly do what you want** (it may have an import plugin but I don't know exactly). However it has a nice online search feature that can search [IEEExplore](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/home.jsp), Google Scholar (not sure if this one works) and [NCBI Pubmed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/). It can also search ISBNs on Amazon and download data into BibTeX. By copying the paper titles you provided into the search fields I was able to find relevant results. For IEEExplore and NCBI Pubmed (Medline) you can also search for the DOI and PMID respectively and it will yield the exact one result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, nice application! For those who wonder (like me a few minutes ago): [How can it export a subset of the bibliography in BibTeX format in JabRef?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82554/11400)

Comment: The web search is indeed a great feature.

Comment: JabRef offers "Tools" > "Entry from plain text". And then "Parse with FreeCite", which uses http://freecite.library.brown.edu/.

Answer (score 1):

**[text2bib](http://text2bib.economics.utoronto.ca/)** seems to do what you want:

- converts a plain text list of references in a wide range of styles to BibTeX
- web service
- requires registration
- supports article, book, incollection, inproceedings, techreport, mastersthesis, phdthesis, and unpublished

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried this service with the example I put into question, the output wasn't very convincing :-) Maybe it would work better if I spend a bit more time understanding what goes wrong, but I feel some pre-processing at least are needed so that the conversion works.

Answer (score 1):

**[apa2bib](http://www.stewart.psych.warwick.ac.uk/software/apa2bib/)** by Neil Stewart:

- it is a perl script
- converts APA-formatted references into bibtex
- command line
- supports books (with volume and edition numbers), chapters in edited books, journal articles, magazine articles (e.g., Science and Nature), and in-press, submitted and unpublished manuscripts.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick shot with all solutions I am aware of:

- [text2bib](http://text2bib.economics.utoronto.ca/) - requires login (see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/7225/18184 for a detailed description)
- [FreeCite](http://freecite.library.brown.edu/) - seems to be free to use. Possibly, the latest fork https://github.com/academia-edu/free_cite should be used
- [ParsCit](http://aye.comp.nus.edu.sg/parsCit/). The WSDL does not validate. The latest source is maintained at https://github.com/knmnyn/ParsCit.
- [apa2bib](https://www.stewart.warwick.ac.uk/software/apa2bib/) (see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/7226/18184 for a detailed description)